# How to use trained BERT model checkpoints for prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, google-cloud-tpu, bert-language-model

I trained the BERT with SQUAD 2.0 and got the `model.ckpt.data`, `model.ckpt.meta`, `model.ckpt.index` (F1 score : 81) in the output directory along with `predictions.json`, etc. using the [BERT-master](https://github.com/google-research/bert)`/run_squad.py`

```
python run_squad.py \
  --vocab_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/vocab.txt \
  --bert_config_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_config.json \
  --init_checkpoint=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt \
  --do_train=True \
  --train_file=$SQUAD_DIR/train-v2.0.json \
  --do_predict=True \
  --predict_file=$SQUAD_DIR/dev-v2.0.json \
  --train_batch_size=24 \
  --learning_rate=3e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs=2.0 \
  --max_seq_length=384 \
  --doc_stride=128 \
  --output_dir=gs://some_bucket/squad_large/ \
  --use_tpu=True \
  --tpu_name=$TPU_NAME \
  --version_2_with_negative=True
```

I tried to copy the `model.ckpt.meta`, `model.ckpt.index`, `model.ckpt.data` to the `$BERT_LARGE_DIR` directory and changed the `run_squad.py` flags as follows to only predict the answer and not train using a dataset:

```
python run_squad.py \
  --vocab_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/vocab.txt \
  --bert_config_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_config.json \
  --init_checkpoint=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/model.ckpt \
  --do_train=False \
  --train_file=$SQUAD_DIR/train-v2.0.json \
  --do_predict=True \
  --predict_file=$SQUAD_DIR/dev-v2.0.json \
  --train_batch_size=24 \
  --learning_rate=3e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs=2.0 \
  --max_seq_length=384 \
  --doc_stride=128 \
  --output_dir=gs://some_bucket/squad_large/ \
  --use_tpu=True \
  --tpu_name=$TPU_NAME \
  --version_2_with_negative=True
```

It throws bucket directory/model.ckpt does not exist error.

How to utilize the checkpoints generated after training and use it for prediction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the trained checkpoints are created in the directory specified by `--output_dir` parameter while training. (Which is `gs://some_bucket/squad_large/` in your case). Every checkpoint will have a number. You have to identify the biggest number; example: `model.ckpt-12345`. Now, set the `--init_checkpoint` parameter in your evaluation/prediction, using the output directory and the last saved checkpoint (The model with the highest number). (In your case, it shall be something like `--init_checkpoint=gs://some_bucket/squad_large/model.ckpt-<highest number>`)

Answer (score 0):

In the second code the FLAG `init_checkpoint` I think it should be:

`--init_checkpoint=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt`

as in the one above, and not `--init_checkpoint=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/model.ckpt`.

If the problem persist, are you using the `multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12` pre-trained models?

Comment: I am using cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16 pre-trained model. I will let you know the results.

Comment: This did not load the trained model but the pre-trained model. Other answer worked. To use trained model, we have to specify the checkpoint number.